# Why are there so many times Harry was told about him having his mother's eyes?

Tags: harry-potter

I can't help but notice that this has been said to him a plethora of times.

How many times was Harry told about him having his mother's eyes?

Was there something important behind the frequent mention?

Comment: Holy cannoli! To the Mathmobile, Batman ... I nominate @DVK to answer this one. Fun question! :)

Comment: Enough that he got tired of hearing it. Almost certainly more than are mentioned in the book.

Comment: Incidentally, I did a text search and the only spot I found with the precise quote "your mother's eyes" was Dumbledore speaking to him in PoA, ch.22. Beyond that, it would essentially take someone reading the entire series explicitly counting occurrences to properly answer.

Comment: The downvote is because this is banal trivia in its most pure form. There's no thought or analysis, just reading and tallying occurrences of an idea.

Comment: @Kevin - I like the occasional trivia question, tbh, even though the site doesn't encourage them. Of course there's no accounting for taste ...

Comment: And when the answer turns out to be seven... We can all smile and nod knowingly as if some new truth, albeit one that we already knew, has been at last revealed.

Comment: @Slytherincess - I'm going to make a bold prediction that the count will be 42. Or 13. I'll try to take a stab at it if I can find time.

Comment: @Kevin - JKR considered "mothers eyes" to be an important thing in the story, so it's not random trivia.

Comment: @Kevin - first time was Hagrid at the light house in HP1

Comment: @DVK yes, I know there are a few others the search (and a couple others I tried) didn't catch. That's part of my point, it will take a human looking over a great deal of text to properly find all occurrences.

Comment: @Kevin - how's that a reason to DV? :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is NOT about a "specific problem that you face", and has not "include[d] details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do."[See help center.](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: @DVK "I don't like this", for any reason, is sufficient reason to downvote. It's VTC where we should be providing justification.  I've done neither for this question, for what it's worth, although I certainly see Kevin's point.

Comment: @Beofett - "It takes a human to look over 7 books" seems like an excuse, not a legitimate reason to dislike the Q. "Can't be answered" is legit... except I am easily proving that one to be incorrect.

Comment: @NominSim - this has been discussed ad nauseum. You are WRONG as per Meta consensus, so please stop trotting out the wrong-for-SFF "specific problem" generic wording: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2865/is-i-am-curious-about-x-sufficient-justification-for-asking-questions-on-sff-s/2869#2869

Comment: @DVK It looks like the new help center from which I quote post dates that meta "discussion". I personally will continue to DV questions like this that are simple trivia, especially ones in which the OP is asking members of the community to do the menial "leg work" for them.

Comment: @NominSim - help center seems to be a simple copy/paste job from Gold Copy for all sites as far as left hand side wording is. I opened a meta to fix it. You have the full right to DV, but don't use terms like "offtopic" that imply VTC

Comment: @DVK I have the full right to VTC too...as IMO this question *is* off-topic, as IMO trivial questions that only require remedial work and show no effort from the OP in that regard don't provide worthwhile content to the site.

Comment: @DVK I was referring more to the "banal trivia in its most pure form" comment, rather than "someone would have to read a lot of books looking for specific text".

Comment: @NominSim DVK is correct that the wording about "specific problems to solve" is simply copy-paste from the generic wording. There's been meta discussion in the past that shows that there's no consensus that that rule really applies to us. If anything, there seems to be a stronger opinion that it does not. You do have the full right to down-vote and/or vote to close, but I believe the VTC does not accurately represent our current policies.

Comment: @Beofett In most places I agree that questions here don't need "specific problems to solve" and are more curiosities of the OP, but if the OP isn't solving a particular problem, then the question should at least be something that contributes to the quality of the content of the site. The seven down votes, two vote to closes, and incomplete answer should be proof enough that this question is unwanted to a degree and is not generating content that users will find useful in the future (too localized is also apparently not a close reason anymore).

Comment: @NominSim That's a fair point.  Note I'm not arguing in support of this question.  Personally, I don't find it interesting. I just don't think it's *that's* bad.

Comment: @Kevin - re: your highly upvoted second comment. I double dare you to read my answer (especially first parts) and repeat your assertion that there's "trivia and no thought or analysis".

Comment: As an FYI - when this question was asked of JKR, one of the times SHE indicated that the asker was quite smart to notice.

Comment: @DVK If the resemblance was so important, then a good question would be "why was it mentioned so often", not "how many times", which is exactly what you have just edited into the question.  Now I think it is clearly on the side of on-topic, interesting, and not "just random trivia".  Great edit, and +1 for the question and your answer.

Comment: @Beofett - Thanks. Given your typical editing skill and heroic rescues, that's a big compliment.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To start off, the mother's eyes were **very important to J.K. Rowling**. This is confirmed with this interview with JKR and Daniel Radcliffe:

> Rowling: And I said, um, “The **only really important thing is that his eyes look like his mother’s eyes**. So if you’re casting Lily, there needs to be a resemblance, but they don’t absolutely have to be green.”  *[(Deathly Hallows 2 DVD)](http://www.hypable.com/2011/11/08/j-k-rowling-discusses-why-harrys-eyes-didnt-have-to-be-green-cutting-a-scene-from-alfonsos-prisoner-script/)*

Also:

> **Q:** Do you know what Harry's parents look like?
> **A:** "Yes. I've even drawn a picture of how they look. Harry has his father and mother's good looks. But **he has his mother's eyes and that's very important in a future book**." *([Loer, Stephanie. "All about Harry Potter from quidditch to the future of the Sorting Hat," The Boston Globe, October 18, 1999](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/1099-bostonglobe-loer.html))*

Of course, we know now that JKR was referring to Snape's story as told in DH.

In addition, the eyes seem to be a pretty big characterization point for JKR - she frequently mentions other characters' eyes, more often than other appearances.

- As an interesting side note, JKR mentioned in CoS that Dobby's eyes were green as well - and of course, he sacrificed his life to save Harry, as Lily did.

---

---

---

**TL:DR: Counts**

```
Mentions of Harry's Green eyes:  20
Of them, comparisons to Lily's:  9 direct, and one implied.
Of them, told to Harry (may be indirectly): All 10
Of them, 2 or 3 are of extremely critical importance to the plot.
```

| Count | Mentioned by | Mentioned to | Harry+Lily? | Snape's memory seen by Harry? | Cite? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hagrid | Harry | 1 |  | HP1:CH4 |
| 1 | Ollivander | Harry | 0 |  | HP1:CH4 |
| 2 | Harry | Harry himself | 2 |  | HP1:CH12 |
| 2 | Dwarf 2/14 | Harry | 0 |  | HP2:CH12 |
| 1 | Dumbledore | Harry | 1 |  | HP3:CH22 |
| 1 | Mrs Weasley | Harry | 0 |  | HP4:CH10 |
| 1 | Rita Skeeter | Harry + ALL | 0 |  | HP4:CH18 |
| 1 | Elphias Doge | Harry + ALL | 1 |  | HP5:CH3 |
| 1 | Narrator | Harry | 1 | Yes | HP5:CH29 |
| 2 | Slughorn | Harry | 2 | Yes | HP6:CH4 |
| 1 | Narrator | N/A + Harry | 0, Implied |  | HP7:CH22 |
| 1 | Narrator | Snape | 1 | Yes | HP7:CH23 |
| 1 | Dumbledore | Snape | 1 | Yes | HP7:CH23 |
| 4 | Narrator | N/A | 0 |  | HP1:CH2;+ HP2:CH1; HP3:CH1; HP4:CH2 |

---

**The most important: Snape and Dumbledore, in DH** (CH22/CH23):

> When the falsk was full to the brim, and Snape looked as though there was no blood left in him, his grip on Harry’s robes slackened.
> “Look…at… me…” he whispered.
> **The green eyes found the black**, but after a second, something in the depths of the dark pan seemed to vanish, leaving them fixed, blank, and empty.

So, before his death, Snape wanted to see Harry's Lily-like eyes.

And, of course, the most important - the Snape's memories from DH:

> Lily’s **bright green eyes** were slits. Snape backtracked at once.

.

> “I thought…you were going…to keep her…safe…”
> “She and James put their faith in the wrong person,” said Dumbledore. “Rather like you, Severus. Weren’t you hoping that Lord Voldemort would spare her?”
> Snape’s breathing was shallow.
> “Her boy survives,” said Dumbledore.
> With a tiny jerk of the head, Snape seemed to flick off an irksome fly.
> **“Her son lives. He has her eyes, precisely her eyes. You remember the shape and color of Lily Evans’s eyes, I am sure?”**
> “DON’T!” bellowed Snape. “Gone…dead…”
> “Is this remorse, Severus?”
> “I wish…I wish I were dead…”
> **“And what use would that be to anyone?” said Dumbledore coldly. “If you loved Lily Evans, if you truly loved her, then your way forward is clear.”**
> Snape seemed to peer through a haze of pain, and Dumbledore’s words appeared to take a long time to reach him.
> “What – what do you mean?”
> **“You know how and why she died. Make sure it was not in vain. Help me protect Lily’s son.”**

The eyes - the resemblance to the love of his life - was what drove Snape to help Dumbledore to the end.

---

**Mentions to Harry by other characters:**

> ... 'Yeh look a lot like yer dad, **but yeh've got yer mum's eyes**.' *(Hagrid, PS, CH4*)

> ... 'Yes, yes. I thought I'd be seeing you soon. Harry Potter.' It wasn't a question. '**You have your mother's eyes.** It seems only yesterday she was in here herself, buying her first wand. Ten and a quarter inches long, swishy, made of willow. Nice wand for charm work.' *(Ollivander, PS, CH4*)

> "Here is your singing valentine: 'His eyes are as green as a fresh pickled toad,'..." *(Singing Dwarf, CoS, CH12 - no comparison to mother)*

> This was partly because he didn't think he could stand Fred and George singing, "His eyes are as green as a fresh pickled toad" one more time *(same place)*

> 'An easy mistake to make,' said Dumbledore softly. 'I expect you're tired of hearing it, but you do look extraordinarily like James. **Except for your eyes -  you have your mother's eyes**.' *(Dumbledore, PoA, CH22)*

> ... his dress robes didn't have any lace on them at all; in fact, they were more or less the same as his school ones, except that they were bottle green instead of black. 'I thought they'd bring out the colour of your eyes, dear,' said Mrs Weasley fondly. *(Mrs Weasley, GoF, CH10  - no comparison to mother)*

> "Tears fill those startlingly green eyes as our conversation turns to the parents he can barely remember." *(Rita Skeeter's article, GoF, CH18 - no comparison to mother)*

> 'Oooh, he looks just like I thought he would,' said the witch who was holding her lit wand aloft. She looked the youngest there; she had a pale heart-shaped face, dark twinkling eyes, and short spiky hair that was a violent shade of violet. 'Wotcher, Harry!'
> 'Yeah, I see what you mean, Remus,' said a bald black wizard standing furthest back  he had a deep, slow voice and wore a single gold hoop in his ear 'he looks exactly like James.'
> **'Except the eyes,' said a wheezy-voiced, silver-haired wizard at the back. 'Lily's eyes.'** *(OotP, CH3)*

> It was one of the girls from the lake edge. She had thick, dark red hair that fell to her shoulders, and **startlingly green almond-shaped eyes. Harry's eyes**. *(Snape's memory as seen by Harry, OotP, CH29)*

> 'You look very like your father.'
> 'Yeah, I've been told,' said Harry.
> '**Except for your eyes. You've got** –'
> '**My mother's eyes, yeah**.' Harry had heard it so often he found it a bit wearing. *(Horace Slughorn, HBP, CH4)*

And, what is undoubtedly second most important occurrence in the series:

> 'You're a good boy,' said Professor Slughorn, tears trickling down his fat cheeks into his walrus mustache. 'And you've got her eyes... just don't think too badly of me once you've seen it...' *(Horace Slughorn, HBP, CH22)*

---

**Mentions by Harry himself**:

> She was a very pretty woman. She had dark red hair and her eyes – **her eyes are just like mine, Harry thought, edging a little closer to the glass. Bright green – exactly the same shape**, but then he noticed that she was crying; smiling, but crying at the same time. *(When first looking into the Mirror of Erised, PS, CH12)*

> ... And slowly, Harry looked into the faces of the other people in the mirror and saw other pairs of green eyes like his, other noses like his *(same place)*

---

**Mentions by the narrator:**

> Harry had a thin face, knobbly knees, black hair and bright-green eyes. *(PS, CH2 - no comparison to mother)*

> Harry, on the other hand, was small and skinny, **with brilliant green eyes** and jet-black hair that was always untidy. *(CoS, CH1 - no comparison to mother)*

> Harry, though still rather small and skinny for his age, had grown a few inches over the last year. His jet-black hair, however, was just as it always had been: stubbornly untidy, whatever he did to it. **The eyes behind his glasses were bright green** *(PoA, CH1 - no comparison to mother)*

> A skinny boy of fourteen looked back at him, **his bright green eyes** puzzled under his untidy black hair. *(GoF, CH2 - no comparison to mother)*

Comment: And... for anyone wishing to be completely grossed out, read the WHOLE article here: http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/features/essays/issue15/HarryHasHisMothersEyes

Comment: That article seems to be reading into it waaay too much...  "<person> has his <mother/father/other ancestor>'s <attribute>" is the most common way to phrase it in English, and anything else sounds convoluted.

Comment: @Izkata - I don't think sounding non-convoluted was the major motivation of the author :)