# Were "green eyes" ever mentioned in the movies?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

Harry having "**green** eyes like Lily" is an important point in the books as discussed here:

[Why are there so many times Harry was told about him having his mother's eyes?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38153/why-are-there-so-many-times-harry-was-told-about-him-having-his-mothers-eyes/38169#38169)

However, for the movies, that didn't work out. According to supplemental materials on DVDs for Philosopher's Stone, Daniel Radcliffe had to wear green contacts and after the first day of shooting (<sub>which was for the ending scene where the trio says good bye to Hagrid at the end of the year</sub>) it was discovered he was allergic to the contacts. So, **Harry never had green eyes in the movies**.

Also, when casting Lily, JKR explicitly stated that she didn't care about anything except she and harry had to have **same eyes**, no matter what color.

So, my question is, was that "same eyes as Lily" continuity successfully implemented in all 8 films?

**More specifically, did they ever mention film-incorrect (*green*) eye color in the films?**

Comment: They never mentioned the eye colour in the film, just that he "has his mother's eyes".

Comment: Isn't Dan allergic to contact lenses? Remember reading about it somewhere somewhere... possible reason :)

Comment: @skip405 - that's exactly what I stated in paragraph 3 of the question. `it was discovered he was allergic to the contacts`. Matter of fact I even included actual source of the fact (DVD supplemental materials)

Comment: sorry 'bout that :) didn't notice it

Answer (score 2):

Actually, no, the term "Green Eyes". was never used in any of the movies like it was in the book. they always and only say "you have your mother's eyes" without any specifications.

In a movie as we already see the actors eyes we dont need any description, therefore they dont specified the color in the movies.

this is what Daniel Radcliffe actually said about his allergies :

> I was actually allergic to the Harry Potter glasses. Because I had
>   these two rings of whiteheads and spots that had come up around my
>   eyes and it took us a week to realize that it was actually the
>   glasses.

the lenses was not the cause of his allergies