# Why are Lily's eyes green and not blue like Harry's?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Pensieve in the Deathly Hallows you can see Lily as a young girl, but her eyes are GREEN eyes not blue eyes like Harry's. A ton of people tell Harry that he has his mother's eyes, but apparently they don't know what they are talking about. Why are Lily's eyes green now?

Comment: Harry's eyes are green in the actual Harry Potter (aka definitely not the movies)

Comment: Perhaps without knowing it, you have asked the question exactly the right way around here: people have often asked why Harry’s eyes weren’t green like Lily’s, but as Rand’s answer shows, Rowling simply insisted that there should be a consistency, whether their eyes were green or blue—and the real question is precisely why _Lily’s_ eyes aren’t blue like Harry’s, since Radcliffe’s eye colour was the limiting factor in the movies. Lily was miscast, or she should have worn coloured contacts or had her eye colour altered in post-production.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the books, both Lily and Harry have green eyes. Daniel Radcliffe, the actor for Harry Potter, [was allergic to the green contacts](http://www.bbc.co.uk/films/2005/11/03/harry_potter_the_goblet_of_fire_2005_interview.shtml), so the filmmakers decided to ignore that detail.

Answer (score 10):

### Because the films are nonsense.

I'm sorry, but that's the long and the short of it. In the books, Harry and Lily both have green eyes. In the films, Daniel Radcliffe (playing Harry) has blue eyes.

This problem was actually [considered](http://www.hypable.com/j-k-rowling-discusses-why-harrys-eyes-didnt-have-to-be-green-cutting-a-scene-from-alfonsos-prisoner-script/) by Rowling and others while the films were being made:

> **Rowling:** Sometimes I’d dig my heels in about the funniest things. I’d say, “Yeah change the costume. Yeah it can happen in that city instead of that city. And all of a sudden, I’d say, ‘But they wouldn’t do that spell. Why would they do that there? So I think sometimes I confused people. But I also remember, right back at the beginning when you were cast I remember David Heyman calling me up and saying, “We’ve tried green contact lenses. We can digitally alter his eye color in post production. How important is it that his eyes are green?”
>
> **Radcliffe:** That I will thank you for.
>
> **Rowling:** And I said, um, “The only really important thing is that his eyes look like his mother’s eyes. So if you’re casting Lily, there needs to be a resemblance, but they don’t absolutely have to be green.” “Oh thank Christ,” he said.

Comment: I was half way of searching for that :D Good find.

Comment: @VanjaVasiljevic Gotta be quick round here.

Comment: According to this question (http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/74242/were-green-eyes-ever-mentioned-in-the-movies) they did just that. Or tried to, anyway.

Comment: Heh, a downvote. Somebody likes the films!

Comment: His eyes weren't green!? That's a major plot point! Jesus...